# What happens when Jon Skeet's reputation exceeds the limit for the data type holding it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fun

So, Jeff, what are you using to store reputation, anyway?

Comment: If they use a long, I think we're safe for a few billion years at least.

Comment: If they use Python's datatypes, there is no limit for his rep.

Comment: @Masi: Storage is always going to be a limit.

Comment: 640K should be enough for anyone....

Comment: Am I really the only one just about tired of questions about Jon Skeet? I mean I respect the guy immensely but give it a break already...

Comment: @Paolo, in this case, the question is about when Rep exceeds the datatype, like the 'twitpocalypse' and because JonSkeet is the leader for the foreseeable future, he cannot be excluded from THIS question.

Comment: His profile views too would need the same data type. Right now its going neck and neck. And for the titan he is, his rep is slightly ahead of profile visits..

Answer (score 93):

Why do you think the rep cap was invented? Defensive coding in the guise of a social mechanism ;)

Answer (score 61):

A new data type is automatically spawned called JonSkeetInt that can hold an infinite value.

Comment: "Automatically" is also another term for "Jon Skeet did it himself".  Obviously he'll change the datatype to one that can hold his new rep.

Comment: Miff, "Multiple references to the same class (Jon Skeet). Maximum recursion exceeded."

Answer (score 54):

2^32 = 4294967296 (unsigned int)

4294967296 / 200 = 21474836.48 (factor in daily rep cap)

21474836.48 / 365 = 58835.1684... (factor in days in a year)

So it would take Jon Skeet (and his descendants presumably) 58835 years to overflow the datatype.

**EDIT**

It has been correctly pointed out that Jon Skeet is not bound by a 200 rep cap.
He in fact has an average of **279.850...** points per day.

74 720 (JonSkeetRep) / 9 (MonthsActive) * (365 / 12) (avgDaysPerMonth)

2^32 = 4294967296 (unsigned int)

4294967296 / 272.949 (JonSkeetDailyRepAvg) = 15735420.5217... (NumberOfDaysToOverflow)

15735420.5217 (NumberOfDaysToOverflow) / 365.25 (AvgDaysInYear) = 43081.2334... (NumberOfYearsToOverflow)

So Jon Skeet would still have to live **another** 43000 years.

**EDIT**

Second edit to reflect the fact that there are *365* days in a year and not *356*

Comment: Set's his calendar.

Comment: devinb, you'll have to re-figure your numbers including the cap-immune accepted-answers. You can still win 15 points an answer even after you've hit the cap, and Skeet has acknowledged that this takes place with him from time to time :)

Comment: That's assuming he never has any answers accepted.  The better calculation would work out the percentage of questions he has accepted and the rate at which questions are asked, too.  I don't have the data set in front of me, sadly.

Comment: For what it's worth, over Tuesday/Wednesday I averaged 502 points per day. Those we pretty remarkable days, admittedly... and I don't think it makes *that* much difference to the feasibility :)

Comment: Who are we to say that Jon Skeet won't live for 43000 years?

Comment: How do you know he hasn't *already* lived for 43000 years? He could be a Highlander. ;)

Comment: THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE....JON SKEET!

Comment: @gnovice: He's English, not Scottish, so he can't be the Highlander. He's obviously the Doctor.

Comment: 365 days in a Solar year, 355 in a lunar year.  356 in neither.

Comment: @geoffc Oh, my dear god. How did no one notice my heonius dysxelia?

Comment: @geoffc: technically, there are 365.2425 days in a year. :)

Comment: @Kip: I'm not adjusting my calculations again.

Comment: @Kip: Meh!  Close enough for horseshoes!  Darn Gregorians!

Comment: @Geoffc: Don't blame Pope Gregory, blame God! If He'd just made the earth spin 0.0664% slower, or if he'd made the earth just a *little* closer to the sun, we wouldn't need leap days...

Comment: @Kip - I think you mean "blame Jon Skeet."

Comment: Not to forget bounties are out of cap limits

Comment: If it does go over the data limit (which is unlikely to happen until the sun blows up), it will either go to a negative value/1 (you can't have rep less than 1), or the rep will change to a string with numbers and a 'k' after it.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet will not alive till next 43,000 years, unless he travel with the speed of 10^23 time faster than light. So, it is quite possible that Jon's reputation might cross the limit to store. Microsoft would surely have to think for some solution. Our next 430 (assuming people live 100 years on an average) generation would have time to think.

Comment: what ? "Jon Skeet would still have to live another 43000 years." !!!!
He needs not to live. The reputation will keep increasing lol

Answer (score 35):

Fact: Jon Skeet's reputation cannot be stored in any datatype.  It exists only in not-yet-invented quantum computing devices.

Fact: The reputation number you see beside Jon Skeet's avatar is merely the projection of his reputation into the 4-dimensional spacetime that humans understand.  His reputation actually occupies most of a 256-dimensional hyperspace.

Fact: Only Jon Skeet is capable of understanding how the previous two facts do not contradict each other.

Comment: This was the best answer

Answer (score 29):

The reputation score that we see for Jon Skeet *is* the overflow

Comment: To be more precise, his reputation overflows approximately once per 23.99999 hours, giving the appearance of increasing by about 250 per day.

Answer (score 16):

It goes to MIN_INT and the rest of us get to look down on him for a few days.

Comment: I almost want Jeff to set Jon's rep to MAX_INT - 200 and see what happens...hilarity might ensue.

Comment: Ha-ha. Irrelevant but funny: I unlocked a new achievement: my month reputation exceeded **10%** of Jon's month reputation.

Answer (score 13):

He saves the Princess!

Comment: I wonder if Jon Skeet does an Up-Up-Down-Down-Left-Right-Left-Right-B-A before posting. Is that his secret?

Comment: I believe it's "Up-Vote Up-Vote Down-Vote Down-Vote Edit Retag Edit Retag Vote-to-close Check-Rep". And yes, he gets to vote four times per question if he so chooses.

Answer (score 10):

**Q.** What happens when Jon Skeet’s reputation exceeds the limit for the data type holding it?

**A.** A stackoverflowpocalypse aka a skeetoverflow

Answer (score 7):

Look, this is Jon Skeet we're talking about.  Obviously we have a new [Jon Skeet fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts):

- When Jon Skeet's reputation threatens to overflow the type used to represent reputation, the type automatically doubles in size to accomodate.

Answer (score 3):

When JS gets MAX_INT score the whole site will fall in a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

We call that The **[Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity)**.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft makes a bigger data type.

Comment: what does microsoft have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

Since we're programmers here, we're try to reproduce the issue when that happens so that most straightforward thing to do would be staring at Marc Gravell's reputation and refreshing the page to see what's going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This data type stores all our reputation

```
JohnSkeet_Var Reputation = 99999999999999^9999999999^99999999999^999999999999
```