# What rights should a user get at 100,000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, fun

Jon Skeet was at 95,917 rep on SO just now. What would be an appropriate power to grant him when he reaches 100,000?

(Similar to [What happens when Jon Skeet’s reputation exceeds the limit for the data type holding it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/what-happens-when-jon-skeets-reputation-exceeds-the-limit-for-the-data-type-hold))

Comment: Ability to delete a random user. *hides*

Comment: @Randell - or just the @random user ;-p

Comment: Who suggested what now?

Comment: Community Wiki please.

Comment: @Henri: Wikified! :)

Comment: How about a "GoSpendSomeTimeWithTheFamilySlashFriends" badge :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A **Hall of Fame badge** would be a nice.

Comment: This is a pretty nice idea.  There should be a limited number of them, though, or maybe Jeff could just hand them out for really notable achievements when he feels like it.

Comment: But it would have to be a platinum badge.

Comment: Why would you need a badge for this? Your rep/score is show everywhere anyways so isn't it redundant?

Comment: @Kelsey, your question would probably apply to all other badges as well.

Comment: @Kelsey: are you saying we don't need no badges? ;)

Comment: @TrueWill: perhaps just not badges based solely on a Reputation #

Comment: @TrueWill:  Badges?  BADGES?!  We don't need no stinkin' badges!

Answer (score 50):

How about the ability to hide exact rep, changing it to just display "Lots"?

In all seriousness, I wouldn't want any time or energy spent on this - at least not for the next year or so. In a year's time we might *almost* be into double digits for 100K users... I'm *sure* there are better things Jeff and the team can do with their time<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Like buying and reading C# in Depth multiple times.

Comment: "buying and reading multiple times" is ambiguous. To clarify, it should be buying multiple times and reading multiple times. :)

Comment: A 'lots' rep would be cool.

Comment: Buying multiple times is the only thing that matters. Reading is not of the essence.

Comment: Like buying and reading C# in Depth *"Lots"*. There I Fixed It For You.

Comment: We have Lots, Lots ^2 and Lots ^ Lots, the latter should not be confused with Lots _&_ Lots.

Comment: @Tim Post: `Lots ^ Lots == 0`; `Lots & Lots == Lots`.

Answer (score 40):

If 10k allows you to see deleted posts, maybe 100k should allow you to see posts that *haven't been posted yet*. Not sure how you'd code it, though ;-p

Comment: Don't worry, Jon himself is able to code it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The code is provided in an answer to a question which will be asked at a later date. Fortunately we've been able to use that code to implement the feature, allowing us view the code. I'm thinking of changing my name to Kyle Reese.

Answer (score 18):

Cake          .

[image]

Comment: The cake is a lie. (Someone had to say it!) ;)

Answer (score 13):

All your base?

(Obviously they are belong to us already really, but this would just make it formal.)

Comment: You have no chance to survive.

Comment: Somebody set up us the bomb!

Comment: For great justice!

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ...

Comment: What do you say!

Answer (score 8):

A big red button that executes a `DROP DATABASE StackOverflow` statement on the database.

Comment: uh-oh *cowers in fear*

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [TheTXI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21501/21506#21506), the only level that is left is moderator, and I do not think completely moderator power should be gained simply based on achieving a certain level of reputation. Moderators have powers needed to oversee the site, and I cannot imagine giving that authority blindly to people of a certain reputation level. As you gain rep you can vote to close questions, but moderators can close with one (among other things) and that to me is a power that the SO team should be in control of, not the rep system. The rep system works well, but it is not flawless; eventually someone would reach 100k that could seriously hurt the site.

Comment: There is the possibility that Jon might not want moderatorship, either...

Comment: I remember he was originally nominated as one for SO with Marc and turned it down then, citing he felt better answering questions rather then moderating the site.

Comment: Moderator privileges are more than one, a 100k user could get merge questions privs, for example. No need to give the 100k user penalty box access.

Answer (score 5):

100.000 points should give you bragging rights.

Comment: I thought it ... does ... give you bragging rights.

Answer (score 4):

The only real power that users at 10k don't already have are those that we moderators have, and I doubt there is any point level you would wan them to attain before being granted those.

Comment: Oh, so there's an **indivisible set of mods privileges**, I guess JJ Thomson is not very happy with you.

Comment: @Vinko the diamond mod powers has never been a secret. They are document on meta if you search for them.

Comment: @Diago: He didn't say they were a secret. Unless I've been misunderstanding the Pledge of Allegiance all these years.

Comment: Wrong! The only real power was the Cornify button :)

Comment: @Diago: TheTXI was referring to mod powers as a single unit. But a 100k user could get, say, merge question privs only instead of the whole mod package.

Comment: Oh, just got it. **indivisible != invisible**

Answer (score 4):

shares of stock in the company?

Comment: Why would that be a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to create one new badge that he gets to define the "achievement rules" for. This would be subject to moderator approval, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough that they get to see the SO [kill screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_screen), do you want a [Steve Wiebe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Wiebe) badge too?

Answer (score -1):

To flag an accepted answer to questions abandoned by the poster.

Comment: This suggestion has come up before in a few different forms, such as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/ It usually doesn't go over too well

Comment: appreciated, realize now that the count is just a metric

Answer (score -2):

A  think something like this:

```
add all user rep then add to User #22656;
```

SQL Queiy