# Is there a total reputation limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when Jon Skeet’s reputation exceeds the limit for the data type holding it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/what-happens-when-jon-skeets-reputation-exceeds-the-limit-for-the-data-type-hold)

Hi,

I was just wondering... What would happen if you (or Skeet) get(s) so much rep. that SQL Server cannot store it? Will it give an error, will you get banned, will you rep. get back to 0 (aka Prestige Mode =D), will StackOverflow get down for a week untill Jeff notices, buys a 128 bit server and updates SQL Server? Or what else would happen?

(Or is this simply impossible because it takes over 200 years because of the daily rep. limit?)

Comment: Dude, it's not Pac Man.

Comment: Guess what this is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/what-happens-when-jon-skeets-reputation-exceeds-the-limit-for-the-data-type-hold

Answer (score 3):

First off, this is a silly question.

Second off, your math is off if rep is stored in a regular signed int. I calculate over 23,000 years

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=2^31+/++250+/+365
```

Comment: You get +15 rep for accepted answers no matter if you've hit the daily cap yet or not.

Comment: And that's why he divided by 250 instead of 200. I know, Jon and a few others have an average closer to 300 or 350, but Michael's point stands: even using a *signed* 32 bit integer an overflow would take *way* more than 200 years.

Answer (score 2):

Jon's already done this a few times. Turns out that it is an unsigned 32-bit int, and it just wrapped around. `<g>`.

Seriously, though, I don't think this isn't a serious concern in even the longest term. For all meaningful interpretations, no there isn't a total cap.